# Player has no attribute 'inventory'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a game, and I added a class for the player like so:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,inventory):
        self.inventory = []
```

Now, when I try to call `Player.inventory` in any way, it gives me an error saying:

> Player has no attribute 'inventory'

I'm not sure what I did wrong, since I also have other classes, like this one that are formatted the exact same way.

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self,name,items):
        self.name = name
        self.items = []
```

That one works just fine, but I don't see a difference in the code.

Comment: The `inventory` attribute is bound to new instances of the class, not the class itself: `Player('some inventory').inventory`.

Comment: `Player` is a class, and as you've defined it, there is no class-level attribute called `inventory`, and there probably *shouldn't* be. Remember, a class is like a template for creating *instances*.

Comment: Also, in Python 3, classes automatically derive from object.  You don't need (object).  Also, you're assigning self.inventory to a list, ignoring the parameter.

Comment: @AaronBentley Some people recommend doing it anyway, for the sake of being explicit and making your code more easily portable to Python2. As someone who dislikes deep inheritance hierarchies, I personally just like the look of `class MyClass:` better though. The one thing I absolutely hate are *empty* parentheses, so `class MyClass():` makes me shudder.

Comment: Aaron, does that mean my classes can just have empty parentheses instead of 'object'?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `inventory` only exist in instantiated objects of `Player` class.

If you call `Player.inventory`, it will only work if it's declared as a class-level attribute, that is to say :

```
class Player(object):
    inventory = []
```

However, you should be careful, because if you do this, then `inventory` will be common for **all** instances of `Player`. Which is probably not what you want in this case.

Comment: Okay, I see. I think it should be fine in this is case, as Player there's only going to be one instance of Player() (The player character, that is).

Comment: You should still avoid doing it. If later you want to have two players it can lead to some bugs you won't understand easily. You should use class attributes only for attributes you actually **want** to share between instances.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I ended up deciding to be safe and make an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Python 3, you no longer need to subclass `object`.  Are you calling `.inventory` on the class `Player` or an instance of `Player`?  The former will result in the error you are seeing, the later will not.

On a side note, you are also over-writing the input parameter `inventory`.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, inventory):
        self.inventory = inventory

# here we instantiate an instance of Player
p = Player([])
p.inventory
# returns:
[]

# here we are calling the class directly
Player.inventory
# raises:
AttributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'inventory'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of Player class and access inventory of that instance.

p = Player(5)
print(p.inventory)

Also, your def __init__ is missing a ':'

Comment: Oops, that was a typo on here. It has that in the code.